# Search for title:"<!" returns wrong results

Tags: bug, search

The search for `title:"<!"` results in [3 Results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title:%22%3C!%22).

But the question [<SELECT> (dropdown) doesn't render correctly when you add a <!DOCTYPE html blah blah blah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954395/select-dropdown-doesnt-render-correctly-when-you-add-a-doctype-html-blah) is not included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It tries to search for whole words only.

In the phrase `<!DOCTYPE`, the `<!` is not a whole word, since it's followed by a letter. Searching for `title:"<!DOCTYPE"` returns [40 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22%3c!DOCTYPE%22).

Comment: Ok, i understand the results now, cause the quotation mark indicate an exact search. But then it is impossible to search for titles that contains "<!".

Comment: Not sure. The search tips seem to indicate that you can use `*` for a wildcard, but that doesn't work here.